# Validating Resource Data with Bean Validation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm using Jersey 2.19 to implement a REST API but I'm having difficulty getting the resource validation to work as I expect.

My resource looks like this.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response test(@NotNull @FormParam("test-param") String testParam, String body)
{
    String response = "test-param is: " + testParam + "\n" + "body is: " + body + "\n";
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(response).build();
}
```

When I issue the following cURL request:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.50.112:8080/myapp/test-validation --data invalid-param=invalid
```

I get the following response in the terminal window:

```
test-param is: null
body is: invalid-param=invalid
```

i.e. the value of `test-param` is `null` as expected but no exception is thrown as defined in the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced002.htm#BABCJEDF).

> If a javax.validation.ValidationException or any subclass of
>   ValidationException except ConstraintValidationException is thrown,
>   the JAX-RS runtime will respond to the client request with a 500
>   (Internal Server Error) HTTP status code.
>
> If a ConstraintValidationException is thrown, the JAX-RS runtime will
>   respond to the client with one of the following HTTP status codes:
>
> 500 (Internal Server Error) if the exception was thrown while
>   validating a method return type
>
> 400 (Bad Request) in all other cases

Comment: Can you provide Curl output also from console

Comment: `--verbose` will give you more verbose data in `response` in `curl` like response code etc

Comment: @AnkitNigam The request was not being rejected when it should have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just stumbled on the answer. Chapter 18 of the [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) states that

> Bean Validation support in Jersey is provided as an extension module
>   and needs to be mentioned explicitly in your pom.xml file (in case of
>   using Maven):

I simply missed this earlier although it would have been helpful if I'd had some kind of warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `public Response test(@FormParam("test-param") @NotNull String testParam, String body)` instead of `public Response test(@NotNull @FormParam("test-param") String testParam, String body)` means `@NotNull`afterwards `@FormParam("test-param")`

Comment: This makes no difference - this missing maven dependency was the cause.